# How to add dependencies to a Model in SageMaker?

Tags: python, machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to deploy a model like this:

```
model_alpha = PyTorchModel(
    entry_point='inference_alpha.py',
    source_dir='code_alpha',
    dependencies = ['module_0',
                    'module_1'],
    role=role,
    model_data=model_data_alpha,
    framework_version="1.7.1",
    py_version='py3',
    code_location='s3://model',
    name='alpha-model',
)
```

But it gives me an error that the folder module_0 is not found. My directory is like this:

```
>>> main/code_alpha
>>>     |------ inference_alpha.py
>>>     |------ module_0
>>>     |------ module_1
```

I'm using the notebook to deploy the model.

```
predictor_alpha = model_alpha.deploy(
    initial_instance_count=1,
    instance_type=instance_type,
    serializer=JSONSerializer(),
    deserializer=JSONDeserializer(),

)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Within the documentation of [PytorchModel()](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/frameworks/pytorch/sagemaker.pytorch.html#sagemaker.pytorch.model.PyTorchModel), you see that this class is based on [FrameworkModel()](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/inference/model.html#sagemaker.model.FrameworkModel) and on and on until the generic [Model()](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/inference/model.html#sagemaker.model.Model).

Therefore, you can use the parameter `source_dir`:

> Path (absolute or relative) to a directory with any other serving
> source **code dependencies** aside from the entry point file. If not
> specified, the model source directory from training is used.

The basic concept is that the sourcedir.tar.gz containing exactly the folder you point to with source_dir is loaded into code_location and then you can use it normally in your script because it runs as an entry_point in that folder itself.

At this point, your script becomes:

```py
model_alpha = PyTorchModel(
    entry_point='inference_alpha.py',
    source_dir=entire_local_path, # full path to code_alpha dir like /home/ec2-user/SageMaker/code_alpha
    role=role,
    model_data=model_data_alpha,
    framework_version="1.7.1",
    py_version='py3',
    code_location=upload_location, # where source_dir will be saved as sourcedir.tar.gz
    name='alpha-model'
)
```

Within your inference script you simply import the forms as follows:

```
from module_0.your_script import your_class, your_func
```

This reasoning applies to every type of sagemaker component. Whether it is a pytorchmodel or a processor or a training process, etc...